# Flexslider images and thumbnails not being displayed in Firefox 36

Tags: 7, views, javascript

I have got a problem that hopefully someone can help me with. I am using the Flexslider module in Drupal 7 and have created a slideshow with thumbnail navigation. This works fine in Chrome, however in Firefox all but the first thumbnail (and the corresponding slider image) are not loading (see the image).

[image]

Here is the generated html source (as seen within Firefox):

```
<div id="flexslider-1" class="flexslider flexslider-processed">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li class="flex-active-slide" data-thumb="http://192.168.123.123/sites/default/files/styles/product_resize/public/tire_photos/tire_reflections_obkx.png?itok=5R46Qo4M" style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative; opacity: 1; display: block; z-index: 2;">
      <div class="views-field views-field-field-product-image">
        <div class="field-content">
          <img width="286" height="286" alt="" src="http://192.168.123.123/sites/default/files/styles/product_resize/public/tire_photos/tire_reflections_obkx.png?itok=5R46Qo4M" typeof="foaf:Image">
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="" style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative; opacity: 0; display: block; z-index: 1;">
      <div class="views-field views-field-field-product-image">
        <div class="field-content"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="" style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative; opacity: 0; display: block; z-index: 1;">
      <div class="views-field views-field-field-product-image">
        <div class="field-content"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-thumbs">
    <li>
      <img class="flex-active" src="http://192.168.123.123/sites/default/files/styles/product_resize/public/tire_photos/tire_reflections_obkx.png?itok=5R46Qo4M">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img class="" src="undefined">
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

You can see that the img link displays source undefined for some reason. Has anyone come across this before? Is this a problem with Firefox or an issue with Flexslider and how would one go about fixing it?

Comment: Have you hard refreshed FF?

Comment: Yes I have flushed the cache on both Drupal and in Firefox.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your site?

Comment: Without access to the site (or at least the relevant HTML from the output), it is nearly impossible fro anyone to help debug this.

Comment: @StefanKorn Added html source as seen by firefox

Comment: Are you sure that the problem only occurs in Firefox, from the code you posted I could hardly imagine that this code would work in Chrome either?

Comment: @StefanKorn The code works in Chrome. It looks like Firefox is somehow expunging the img tag. In Chrome the img tag has the proper source information. It is very weird and I don't understand it.